# Low latency two-phase protocol

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, protocols

I'm look recommendations on how to achieve low latency for the following network protocol:

1. Alice sends out a request for information to many peers selected at random from a very large pool.
2. Each peer responds with a small packet <20kb.
3. Alice aggregates the responses and selects a peer accordingly.
4. Alice and the selected peer then continue to the second phase of the protocol whereby a sequence of 2 requests and responses are performed.
5. Repeat from 1.

Given that steps 1 and 2 do not need to be reliable (as long as a percentage of responses arrive back we proceed to step 3) and that 1 is essentially a multicast, this part of the protocol seems to suit UDP - setting up a TCP connection to these peers would add an addition round trip.

However step 4 needs to be reliable - we can't tolerate packet loss during the subsequent requests/responses.

The conundrum I'm facing is that UDP suits 1 and 2 and TCP protocol suits 4. Connecting to every peer selected in 1 is slow especially since we aim to transmit just 20kb, however UDP cannot be tolerated for step 4. Handshaking the peer selected in 4. would require an additional round trip, which compared to the 3 round trips still is a considerable increase in total time.

Is there some hybrid scheme whereby you can do a TCP handshake while transmitting a small amount of data? (The handshake could be merged into 1 and 2 and hence doesn't add any additional round trip time.)

Is there a name for such protocols? What should I read to become more acquainted with such problems?

Additional info:

- Participants are assumed to be randomly distributed around the globe and connected via the internet.
- The pool selected from in step 1. is on the order of 1000 addresses and the the sample from the pool on the order of 10 to 100.

Comment: There is an experimental variation of TCP called "TCP Fast Open" which carries data before handshaking is complete. See RFC 7413. Beyond that, it would help if you specified a little more about your networking environment. Are all participants connected via a local network, or are they arbitrarily dispersed around the Internet, or what?

Comment: "TCP Fast Open" sounds good. I've edited OP to add some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough detail here to do a well-informed criticism. If you were hiring me for advice, I'd want to know a lot more about the proposal, but since I'm doing this for free, I'll just answer the question as asked, and try to make it practical rather than ideal.

I'd argue that UDP is not suitable for the early part of your protocol. You can't just multicast a single packet to a large number of hosts on the Internet (although you can do it on typical LANs). A 20KB payload is not the sort of thing you can generally transmit in a single datagram in any case, and the moment messages fail to fit in a single datagram, UDP loses most of its attraction, because you start reinventing TCP (badly).

Probably the simplest thing you can do is base your system on HTTP, and work with implementations which incorporate all the various speed-ups that Google (mostly) has been putting into HTTP development. This includes TCP Fast Open, and things like it. Initiate connections out to your chosen servers; some will respond faster than others: use that to your advantage by going with the quickest ones. Don't underestimate the importance of efficient implementation relative to theoretical round-trip time, by the way.

For stage two, continue with HTTP as before. For efficiency, you could hold all the connections open at the end of phase one and then close all the ones except your chosen phase two partner. It's not clear from your description that the phase two exchange lends itself to the HTTP model, though, so I have to hand-wave this a bit.

It's also possible that you can simply hold TCP connections open to all available peers more or less permanently, thus dodging the cost of connection establishment nearly all the time. A thousand simultaneous open connections is large, but not outrageous in most contexts (although you may need to tweak OS settings to allow it). If you do that, you can just talk whatever protocol you like over TCP. If it's a truly peer-to-peer protocol, you only need one TCP connection per pair. Implementing this kind of thing is tricky, though: an average programmer will do a terrible job of it, in my experience.

Comment: This was very helpful. 

The multicast request itself would be tiny (a single flag). If the responses shrunk to fit reliably in one packet (is it ~1kb?) would it then make UDP viable for the first stage?

Holding all the TCP connections open is another thing I considered and given your endorsement it seems a bit more attractive than I originally imagined.

"If it's a truly peer-to-peer protocol, you only need one TCP connection per pair."
I'm using Rust+Tokio which is relatively high level and gives async out the box. Is there any common pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: You won't be able to multicast UDP: you'll be sending a number of identical packets to different addresses, one after the other. Handling UDP and payload size is a tricky business, because the maximum size depends on the network itself. There's also the possibility of fragmentation if the packet exceeds a size limit at some point. This increases the probability that the packet will fail to arrive intact. I'd suggest 512 bytes is a good size, but I haven't done any network measurement in a long time to see what's really out there.

Comment: Regarding TCP, a busy web server or mail server can easily have a thousand simultaneous sessions going on, so it's possible, but not necessarily easy. With regards to coding, ensure that **everything** is asynchronous and event-driven (not an easy coding style in most languages). Put tight timeouts on your sockets, and be prepared to drop connections the moment they under-perform. TCP by nature will retry forever if needs be. Don't let it: kill and temporarily suspend any connection that gets sluggish.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is already asynchronous in the current implementation. 

"'not an easy coding style in most languages" - in Rust this is done by futures and lots of combinators, it's a bit tricky but I've got relatively nifty with it.